# AngularJS: Refresh DOM when filtered value has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a filter that can refresh angular expressions inside HTML when filtered value has changed. So I'm basically doing [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/FQCISd7asu1P1WxfXRyS):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="GreetingApp" ng-controller="GreetingCtrl">
    <p>{{ appName }}</p>
    <h1>{{ name | greeting }}</h1>
    <br />

    Greetword:
    <input ng-model="greetWord" />
    <button ng-click="GreetingService.setGreetWord(greetWord)">Use "{{ greetWord }}"</button>
    <br />
    <br />

    Name:
    <input ng-model="name" />

  </body>

</html>
```

Inside `script.js`:

```
angular.module('GreetingApp', [])

  .controller('GreetingCtrl', ['$scope', 'GreetingService', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function($scope, GreetingService, $rootScope, $timeout) {

    $scope.appName = 'Greetings!';

    $scope.greetWord = 'Hello';

    $scope.name = 'World';

    $scope.GreetingService = GreetingService;
  }])

  .service('GreetingService', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$timeout',
    function($rootScope, $q, $timeout) {

    var service = {

      greetWord: 'Hello',

      setGreetWord: function(word) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

          $rootScope.$applyAsync(angular.bind(this, function() {
            this.loadGreetWord(word);
            deferred.resolve();
            $rootScope.$new;
          }));

        return deferred.resolve();
      },

      loadGreetWord: function(word) {
        this.greetWord = word;
      },

      getGreetingFor: function(name) {
        return this.greetWord + ' ' + name;
      }

    };

    return service;
  }])

  .filter('greeting', ['GreetingService',
    function(GreetingService) {

    return function(name) {
      return GreetingService.getGreetingFor(name);
    };
  }]);
```

When the value of `GreetingService.greetWord` changes, I'd like to use it in the filter and update the text in views. However when `$rootScope.$applyAsync` is called I can't see the change. Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Binding service to the view is a bad practice and you must avoid it. Instead do that inside the controller.

```
GreetingApp.controller("GreetingCtrl", function($scope, GreetingService) {
   $scope.greetWord = GreetingService.greetWord;
   $scope.setGreetWord = function(greetWord) {
      if(greetWord) {
         GreetingService.setGreetWord(greetWord);
      }
   }
});
```

In your View:

As you want to filter it using greetWord, you can just set it to the filter. It will take care of filtering :)

```
  <li ng-repeat="item in names | filter:greetWord">
        <greeting name="item.name"></greeting>
  </li>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion on binding a service to scope! However, what I'd like to do is to update `{{ name | greeting }}` when we call `GreetingService.setGreetWord()`. Is that possible?

Comment: Check this: http://jsbin.com/jozacu/1/edit?html,js,output please remove those $rootScope.evalAsync etc. It's not required

Comment: Sorry, it hasn't solved the problem. Also I realised that in your JSBin the code isn't modified in any way?

Comment: Oh sorry hope I provided previous version URL. Will share the correct URL in sometime.. Traveling currently

Comment: did you check the jsbin demo?